# How to take results from form after button click (JavaScript and HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, html-select

I'm pretty new to HTML and Javascript, and I'm trying to do this simple program where I fill a form and, when I hit "Submit", the results are saved (doesn't matter whether in text file, in alert, or whatever, I just want to be able to save the results). I have this code so far:

```js
    function myFunction(){
        var Gender = document.getElementbyName('Gender').value;
        var Status = document.getElementbyName('Status').value;
        alert(Gender, Status);
    }
```

```css
                h2 {margin-top: 50px}
                input {margin-top: 50px}
                label {display: inline-block; width: 180px; text-align: left; margin-top: 15px}
```

```html
        <h1>Form</h1>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">  

             <h2>Enter: </h2>

                <label> Gender: </label>               
                    <select name='Gender'>                
                        <option value='Female' selected>Female</option>
                        <option value='Male'>Male</option>               
                    </select><br />                
                <label>Status: </label>                
                    <select name='Status'>               
                        <option value='Single' selected>Single</option>
                        <option value='Married'>Married</option>             
                    </select><br />                     
  <input type = 'Submit' id="Submit" onclick="myFunction()" value = 'Submit'>          
  </form>
```

The page is displayed as I want it, but when I fill in the values and click submit, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? Again, I'm very new at this so I don't have yet a good handle on all the basic stuff. I looked up some solutions online, but nothing has worked with me so far, and most solutions seemed geared for "texts" and not "option",  so I was wondering if there was a way to handle that kind of input.

Any help, or reference, would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just want to adjust your javascript a little to stay within your example. It's getElementsByName (note the S), and since there can be multiple, you'll get the 0th.

```
<script>
function myFunction(){
var Gender = document.getElementsByName('Gender')[0].value;
var Status = document.getElementsByName('Status')[0].value;
alert(Gender + ' - '+ Status);
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cdwz6x0n/4/

Answer (score 1):

The issue you were having is `document.getElementbyName` does not exist, but `document.getElementsByName` is an alternative that you can use. Also, because your input was set to `type="submit"`, it was attempting to submit your form data to a location that was unset so I changed that to `type="button"`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var Gender = document.getElementsByName('Gender')[0].value;
  var Status = document.getElementsByName('Status')[0].value;
  alert('Gender: ' + Gender + ', Status: ' + Status);
}
```

```css
h2 {
  margin-top: 50px
}

input {
  margin-top: 50px
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 15px
}
```

```html
<h1>Form</h1>

<h2>Enter: </h2>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <label> Gender: </label>
  <select name='Gender'>
    <option value='Female' selected>Female</option>
    <option value='Male'>Male</option>
  </select><br />
  <label>Status: </label>
  <select name='Status'>
    <option value='Single' selected>Single</option>
    <option value='Married'>Married</option>
  </select><br />
  <input type='button' id="Submit" onclick="myFunction()" value='Submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: I see, thank you!! One question, though, I corrected the error in a notepad, saved it as an htm file then ran the file as a Chrome HTML document. When I click submit, it still doesn't do anything. Isn't it supposed to work no matter where I run it?